# Why .scroll() doesn't work anymore when I scroll the page manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
// ----------------------------------------- Part 1 --------------------------------------

var anchor = location.hash;
if(anchor.length){
    if (anchor.indexOf("faq") >= 0){
        if ( $(anchor).length ) {
            var elem_question = $(anchor);
            $(anchor).css('background-color','#FC9A24'); // change background color to orange for 1 sec  becase this is selected
            setTimeout(function() { elem_question.css({"background-color":"transparent", "transition":"background-color 1.5s ease"});}, 400);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:elem_question.offset().top-80}, '500'); // for scrooling
            return false;
        }
    }

}


// ----------------------------------------- Part 2 --------------------------------------

doc.scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y > 37) {
        $("#header").addClass("header_shadow");
    }

    else
        $("#header").removeClass("header_shadow");
});
```

When there is an anchor (like `#faq-1`) in the URL of the page (`Part 1` executes), then `Part 2` doesn't work anymore. It means I don't see that shadow to the header. How can I fix this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

you need to trigger the scroll event

```
var anchor = location.hash;
if(anchor.length){
    if (anchor.indexOf("faq") >= 0){
        if ( $(anchor).length ) {
            var elem_question = $(anchor);
            $(anchor).css('background-color','#FC9A24'); // change background color to orange for 1 sec  becase this is selected
            setTimeout(function() { elem_question.css({"background-color":"transparent", "transition":"background-color 1.5s ease"});}, 400);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:elem_question.offset().top-80}, '500'); // for scrooling
            doc.scroll();//trigger the scroll
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Still I don't see the shadow .. and the interesting part is, apparently `Part 2` code will be ignored totally. Because when there is an anchor, then I don't see that *shadow under header* even when I scroll the page by mouse.

Comment: do a console.log in the scroll event and see if it fires if the anchor is present

Comment: I did it. No scroll doesn't fire anymore. Also when I add `doc.scroll()` (as you said), it throws `jquery-1.8.2.min.js?v=1:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem resolved by changing the position of `Part 1` and `Part 2`. Here is the working version:

```
// ----------------------------------------- Part 2 --------------------------------------

doc.scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y > 37) {
        $("#header").addClass("header_shadow");
    }

    else
        $("#header").removeClass("header_shadow");
});


// ----------------------------------------- Part 1 --------------------------------------

var anchor = location.hash;
if(anchor.length){
    if (anchor.indexOf("faq") >= 0){
        if ( $(anchor).length ) {
            var elem_question = $(anchor);
            $(anchor).css('background-color','#FC9A24'); // change background color to orange for 1 sec  becase this is selected
            setTimeout(function() { elem_question.css({"background-color":"transparent", "transition":"background-color 1.5s ease"});}, 400);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:elem_question.offset().top-80}, '500'); // for scrooling
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

In the version in the question, I guess the order of executing affects on the scroll and made it disabled.